# No se guarda la altura de los widgets en kivyMD

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

tengo este **documento .kv** para mi app en kivy con python. Estoy tratando de usar el módulo de **size_hint:()** para cuadrar la altura de los widgets, el problema es que cuando aplico el módulo: **"size_hint: (.5, .3)"** en un solo widget, funciona y el widget se hace más bajo. Pero al aplicarlos a todos entonces deja de tener efecto y los widgets vuelven a su tamaño original. Si alguien sabe porqué sucede esto y como solucionarlo, les estaré agradecido.

```
<Marco_inicio_de_sesion>

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size: root.width, root.height
        spacing: 20
        padding: 50

        TextInput:
            hint_text: "Usuario"
            multiline: False
            size_hint:(.5, .3)
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
            

        TextInput:
            hint_text: "Contraseña"
            multiline: False
            size_hint:(.5, .3)
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}


        Button:
            text: "Iniciar Sesión"
            size_hint:(.5, .3)
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}

        Button:
            text: "Registrarse"
            size_hint:(.5, .3)
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}

        Button:
            text: "Iniciar Sesión con Google"
            size_hint:(.5, .3)
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`size_hint` puede ser confuso, la clave esta en entender que no hace referencia al tamaño del widget en si mismo, sino al del padre (`Layout` o `Window`). Indica cuanto espacio debe ocupar en relación a su padre. Es decir, 0.5 no especifica que el widget debe reducir su tamaño asignado a la mitad, sino que debe ocupar la mitad del tamaño de su padre. En realidad no es tan simple, hay dos casos:

- Si el layout no necesita tener en cuenta el tamaño de todos sus widgets hijos para calcular el tamaño de uno de ellos, `size_hint` representa una proporción directa del tamaño del layout. Por ejemplo, en un BoxLayout con orientación vertical, si estableces un `size_hint(0.5, 1)` el widget tendrá la mitad del ancho del BoxLayout. En este caso el ancho del widget no esta influenciado por sus hermanos, ya que estamos en un BoxLayout vertical.
- Cuando el layout tiene que tener en cuenta al resto de widgets hijos para calcular el tamaño de uno de ellos, su `size_hint` representa una fracción de la suma de los `size_hint` de todos los widgets hermanos. Por ejemplo, si tienes el mismo BoxLayout vertical de antes y tres widgets con  `size_hint` de (1, 1), (1, 0.3) y (1, 0.7), el primer widget tendrá una altura del 50% de la altura del padre (1 / (1 + 0.3 + 0.7) * 1), el segundo el 15% y el tercero el 35%. La diferencia con respecto al primer caso es que en un BoxLayout vertical el layout debe repartir la altura entre todos sus hijos, a diferencia de la anchura.

En tu caso defines 5 widgets todos con `size_hint_y` de 0.3, por lo que la suma es 1.5 y obviamente 1/1.5*0.3 = 0.2, es decir cada widget ocupa el 20% de la altura del BoxLayout, lo que es lo mismo que no especificar el `size_hint`, simplemente se reparten el alto a partes iguales.

Si solo estableces el size_hint_y para uno de los cinco la cosa cambia, el resto de widgets tienen un `size_hint_y` por defecto de 1, por lo que tenemos:

```
1 / (0.3+1+1+1+1) * 0.3 = 0.7
```

Por lo que ese widget ocupara aproximadamente 7% del alto del layout y los otros tres el 23% aproximadamente.

---

Dependiendo de que quieras conseguir y de la estructura completa de tu app podrias optar por varias soluciones. Una forma de reducir el tamaño de todos los widgets es usar otros layouts para agrupar. Por ejemplo, en vez de aplicar el `size_hint` sobre cada uno de los widgets, lo aplicas sobre un layout padre común:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder


kv = """
AnchorLayout:
    anchor_x: "center"
    anchor_y: "top"
    size: root.width, root.height
    
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        size_hint: (0.5, 0.5)
        spacing: 20
        padding: 50
        
        TextInput:
            hint_text: "Usuario"
            multiline: False
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
            
        TextInput:
            hint_text: "Contraseña"
            multiline: False
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}

        Button:
            text: "Iniciar Sesión"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}

        Button:
            text: "Registrarse"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}

        Button:
            text: "Iniciar Sesión con Google"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5}
"""
    
class TestApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]